# How to use splice in Angular to remove an item from a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, angularjs, loops

The template looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="revision in revisions" id="revision_{{revision.id}}">
    <td><a href="#/wiki/revision/{{ revision.id }}">{{ revision.title }}</a></td>
    <td>(<a href="#/wiki/revision/edit/{{ revision.id }}">Edit</a> | </td>
    <td><a ng-click="revisionDisappear($index)">Delete</a>)</td>
</tr>
```

and the controller like this:

```
$scope.revisionDisappear = function($index) {
    $scope.revision.revisions[0].splice($index, 1);
};
```

the error I get is: `Cannot read property 'revisions' of undefined` so I presume the issue is somewhere in the controller. Could any of you tell me what would the right way of doing it be?

Comment: Please update this question with more detail and possibly a working plunkr example

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your `ng-repeat` function, your scope contains `revisions` array and `ng-repeat` iterates over them and creates isolate scopes with a revision variable representing each item in the `revisions`.

It looks like your controller is outside of `ng-repeat`, thus it doesn't see scopes containing the individual `revision` instances, but it does see the original `revisions` array, so you should just be able to `splice` it directly.

```
 $scope.revisions.splice($index, 1)
```

Comment: That gives me `TypeError: Cannot call method 'splice' of undefined`

Comment: Can you create a plunker/jsfiddle that shows your problem. The problem  is definitely with scope visibility in your controller and a lot depends on where the controller is used vs the ng-repeat directive

Comment: The plunker doesnt work since youre injecting services into your controllers that are not defined in the plunker, however i can see cross pollination of scope models across unrelated controllers. A general solution is if you need to share data between controllers, you need to use a service. A more specific answer would require you to put a bit more detail into your question and provide a working example of your problem

Answer (score 0):

### You may also want to check your item's id...

Its also wise to report to your system that a change has been made -- this is the first step toward *Event-Driven Architectures*.

In this case, your code may look something like this:

HTML:

```
<td><a ng-click="revisionDisappear(revision)">Delete</a>)</td>
```

JS:

```
$scope.revisionDisappear = function(revision) {
    for(var i = 0, len = $scope.revisions.length; i < len; i++){
        if($scope.revisions[i].id === revision.id){
            var removed = $scope.revisions[i].splice(i, 1);  // returns an array
            $scope.$emit('myRevisionModule://removed/revision', removed[0]);
            break; // !!!
        }
    }
};
```

Its critical that you `break;` after calling `splice` on an array while inside of your loop. That is, if you remove the `nth` item, your loop will continue to the next iteration -- however, this last item has been removed so referencing a property off of `undefined` throws a `Type Error`.

Hope this helps!